How to include package.json file in visual studio code to visual studio, I did everything on VScode but don't know how to do it on VS
I made a web app on Visual Studio Code and want to transfer the project to Visual Studio
I don't plan to use c# and just do it using nodejs and expressjs
I tried opening the "Open a project or solution" options but didn't see package.json

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
